# lessc Syntax error no matter what

Tags: css, less

I have a less file that I am trying to compile, it contains (and the files all exist)

```
@import 'effects.less';
@import 'fonts.less';
@import 'normalise.less';
@import 'vars.less';
```

The error I'm getting is

```
SyntaxError: Operation on an invalid type in web.less:null:-1
1 @import 'fonts.less';
```

I have tried saving the file as utf-8 without BOM and still no success.

Here is the output of file -I web.less

```
web.less: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

I've tried running inconv on it to be sure but still this error persists

```
iconv -f us-ascii -t utf-8 web.less > web.less
```

`lessc -v` returns

```
lessc 1.3.3 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]
```

This is driving me mental, what is wrong with it?

[edit]

I did not copy and paste the import rules. They are hand typed, fwiw the editor I'm using is Sublime Text 2 to create these files and I'm on OSx and lessc was installed via npm (I've tried updating it already)

Comment: If your file doesn't have chars out of the reduced ascii range, it's not different from an UTF-8 file, no need to convert it.

Comment: *Did you copy/paste the @import rule?

Comment: It was a desperate attempt, no idea what could be causing this. I did not copy paste (I deleted the file and retyped everything this morning by hand to be sure.)

Comment: What's in fonts.less ? Does this file compile fine ?

Comment: Super weird, I have no idea. Sorry.

Comment: Quick test, yes fonts.less compiles correctly. As does effects.less

Comment: It's actually caused by vars.less.. something going on in there. Will report back very soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenating strings in less isn't done using the `+` operator but using string interpolation.

Replace

```
@default: @bwFont + ', ' + @backups;
```

with

```
@default: "@{bwFont},@{backups}";
```

Comment: Even better than my answer, this is in my mind the answer to my question (in a round-about way) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the issue was in my vars.less file the contents being

```
@bwFont: 'blackwell-book';
@backups: Arial,sans-serif;
@default: @bwFont + ', ' + @backups;
```

The issue was with the concat operation for `@default` changing it to just be

```
@default: 'blackwell-book', Arial,sans-serif;
```

Fixes everything. I will check for a bug report and report if not found.

Thanks guys.